# Using AspNet Razor to send emails built from templates

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to create a method to compile a Razor view (I'm using Asp Net 5) and convert it to a string that I can send as an email body. So far what I have is:

```
             MailMessage mailmessage  = new MailMessage("email@test.com",email);

        var parser = new RazorParser(new CSharpCodeParser(),
            new HtmlMarkupParser(),
            null);
        var result = parser.Parse(new StringReader("<p>Hello world. The time is @DateTime.UtcNow</p>"));

        mailmessage.Body = ""; // What to put here?

        mailmessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.test.com");
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.Credentials = // Removed
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        return smtp.SendMailAsync(mailmessage);
```

I can not figure out what I need to do to convert the ParserResult to something usable for an email body, I've been digging through the AspNet source code but no luck yet, does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this method to get the contents of a view from the current controller as a string:

```
private string getViewContents(string viewName, object model)
{
  var writer = new StringWriter();

  ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
  var data = new ViewDataDictionary();
  data.Model = model;

  var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, data, new TempDataDictionary(), writer);
  viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, writer);

  return writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
}
```

Comment: I found a problem in this code.  Try it again if you got errors.

Comment: Is there a way to do this out of a controller? I'm trying to do it in the MessageServices file so I can just pass it the name of the view and the model and have it compile and send the email from any controller. If not I suppose I can just add this as an extension method to Controller and pass the result to the default SendEmail method.

Comment: I would just add a parameter to this function which accepts a ControllerContext object.  That seems like the simplest way to go.

Comment: Thanks, can you help me figure out which using statements I need to add? I'm using VSCode and it's having trouble giving me intellisense, it says that ControllerContext doesn't even exist :P

Comment: You should need: System.Web.Mvc and System.IO

Comment: Isn't System.Web.Mvc gone in Asp.Net 5?

Comment: No, System.Web.Mvc is still used.